# Exctracting numbers from a string

Tags: python, regex

I have a big text string. Consider a text version of an invoice. In that I have multiple lines of text and numbers.

One of the text line in that bigger string is below:

```
"Freight charge - 139 KG @ USD 0.70/KG                                                                                              Zero Rated                             97.30\n"
```

PLS scroll the above string to the right. It has more elements than what it first appears above.

I want to extract 97.30 from it. The issue is the no. of digits on the left and right of "." can be any digit.

So I tried this,

```
freight_charge = re.search(r"Freight charge.*Zero Rated\s*(.*)",s).group(1)
```

and it works and I get 97.30

I want to avoid using "Zero Rated" in between as I am not sure if that would remain consistent across same string, so I tried this:

```
freight_charge = re.search(r"Freight charge.*([\d]*\.[\d]*)",output)


print(freight_charge.group())
print(freight_charge.group(1))    


Freight charge - 139 KG @ USD 0.70/KG                                                                                              Zero Rated                             97.30
.30
```

This only extracts 0.30. It does show that the pattern is able to get the whole string but sub group is only extracting the numbers after decimal.

Not sure why 97 before that is not getting extracted when I have put [\d]* before the period in the group sub expression

Comment: pls scroll to the right. it exists there

Comment: could the value also be `.30` if there was only `.30`? the `\d*\.\d*` could also match a single dot as the digits are optional.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that `.*` will first match until the end of the line. Then the regex will backtrack to the first location where it can produce a match, which is matching the dot as that is not optional.

If you don't want to match a dot only but do want to match for example `.30` or `30` if that is the only value, you could add matching a space before and match 1 or more digits after the dot or only digits.

```
Freight charge.* (\d*\.?\d+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bPn3vK/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/k6M8eF)

*Example code*

```
import re
s= r"Freight charge - 139 KG @ USD 0.70/KG                                                                                              Zero Rated                             97.30\n"
freight_charge = re.search(r"Freight charge.* (\d*\.?\d+)",s).group(1)
print(freight_charge)
```

*Output*

```
97.30
```

Answer (score 1):

you can simply use this regex `/(\d+.\d+)/g` and capture the 3rd group.. below is the JS sample, but will work with Python as well

```js
  var str = "Freight charge - 139 KG @ USD 0.70/KG                                                                                              Zero Rated                             97.30\n";
  var patt = /(\d+.\d+)/g;
 var result = str.match(patt);
 
 console.log(result[2])
```

Result: **97.30**

Comment: hi pls scroll the text string to the right. The full string has more elements after 0.70/kg . What I want is 97.30 at the very end.

Comment: @Baktaawar yup, that is the result of my regex, please run the code snippet :)

Comment: we have to use Freight charge as the first pattern string as this string is one line in a bigger string. So just cant use the digits pattern in that case as it might pick up some other digits from some other lines

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same as you did but just replace * with + that will get one or more numbers before . and one or more numbers after

```
freight_charge = re.search(r"Freight charge.* (\d*\.\d*)",output)
print(freight_charge.group(1))
```

output

```
97.30
```

Comment: sorry. Pls scroll the string to the right. The no. I want is right at the end and not 0.70. Its 97.30 which is what I want.

Comment: Changed to match the 97.30

Comment: isnt this same as what I had? Why am I not getting it then?

Comment: The space between the (\d*\.\d*) and .* makes the difference because without space than the 9 is part of .*

Comment: Got it. Thanks a ton. Possible to help on this? 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61587070/how-to-extract-specific-whole-subheadings-data-from-a-string/61587207#61587207