# How to extract specific whole subheadings data from a string

Tags: python, regex

I have a bigger text string which has a bunch of lines. A few of these lines are of the form of bill of materials as follows: Pls scroll to the right to see the complete data.

```
DESCRIPTION                                                                                                                                             
GST IN USD               CHARGES IN USD\n    Freight charge - 139 KG @ USD 
0.70/KG                                                                                              
Zero Rated                             97.30\n    Warehouse Handling - 
Gateway 
Fee                                                                                                   
Zero Rated                             50.00\n    Handling - Origin Handling                                                                                                         
Zero Rated                             65.00\n    Delivery Cartage                                                                                                                   
Zero Rated                             75.00\n    Documentation fee                                                                                                                  
Zero Rated                             32.50\n\n\n\n\n
```

The above is a text representation of the actual pdf invoice which looks like below:

[image]

I need a final output for the form:

```
{
  "Freight Charge": 97.30, 
  "Warehouse Handling": 50.00, 
  "Origin Handling": 65.00, 
  "Delivery cartage": 75.00
  "Documentation fee": 32.50
}
```

So basically extracting the main cost of the corresponding description sub headings.

However the problem is the description sub headings are not fixed strings. If that was the case, I can try something like :

```
delivery_cartage = re.search(r"Delivery Cartage.*Zero Rated\s*(.*)",output).group(1)

documentation_fee = re.search(r"Documentation fee.*Zero Rated\s*(.*)",output).group(1)
```

For different text files, the sub headings under description are different keeping the rest of the columns (GST in USD) and Charges In USD columns fixed.

For ex. for another text file, I have the following sub headings under DESCRIPTION

```
DESCRIPTION                                                                                                                         
GST IN USD                CHARGES IN USD\n    
Freight charge - 833.5 KG @ USD 0.68/KG                                                                                        Zero   Rated                        566.78\n    
Terminal Handling Charges   IOR FEE                                                                                                Zero   Rated                      1,200.00\n    
Handling - 833.5 KG @ USD 0.50/KG                                                                                                  Zero   Rated                        416.75\n    
Delivery Cartage - 833.5 KG @ USD 0.25/KG                                                                                          Zero   Rated                        208.38\n    
Fuel Surcharge - 833.5 KG @ USD 0.25/KG                                                                                            Zero   Rated                        208.38\n    
War Risk Surcharge - 833.5 KG @ USD 0.14/KG                                                                                        Zero   Rated                        116.69\n\n\n\n\n
```

Which looks like below

[image]

As you can see this one has few different sub headings : Fuel Surcharge, Terminal Handling Charges , War Risk Surcharges etc.

```
{

  "Weight" : 398.00 KG,
  "VOLUME":4.99 M3,
  "CHAREGABLE":833.500 KG, 
  "PACKAGES" : 12 PLT, 

  "MAWB": 2394746354,
  "HAWB": SBCA20083746,

  "Freight Charge": 566.78, 
  "Terminal Handling Charges": 1200.00, 
  "Handling - 833.5": 416.75, 
  "Delivery Cartage": 208.38
  "Fuel Surcharge": 208.38
  "War Risk Surcharge:116.69
}
```

***This is the full text string*** with the bold black are the keys of the dictionary and red are the values for the corresponding keys I want extracted.

```
\n\n    INVOICE ABC005109692                                                                                                                                              Page 1 of 1\n\n                     ABC SERVICES PTE LTD (31-Jan-20\n                     CUSTOMER ID             SGARSCDABS\n                    SOUTH ST 3 #08-01                                                                               SHIPMENT                SSISA018830\n                     SINGAPORE 1234672                                                                                         DUE DATE                01-Mar-20\n                                                                                                                              TERMS                   30 days from Inv. Date\n                                                                                                                              INCOTERM                DDP - Delivered Duty Paid\n      **Try the e-Booking tool available for you through the IRIS portal**                               CONSOL NUMBER     C065938576823\n********************************************************************************************************************\n     SHIPMENT DETAILS                                                                                                SHIPPER                                                                                             CONSIGNEE\n    KUSU PTE LTD C/O ABC SERVICES PTE LTD                                                    MPMS ENTERPRISE - (ABC09987-V)\n    REFERENCE\n    128465504968, 53389/233973\n    GOODS DESCRIPTION\n    NETWORK BUNDLE,                     BASIC DEGREE, 1 RAIL INVOICE NO: 298773 SHIPPING REF: 094739\n    IMPORT CUSTOMS BROKER                                                **WEIGHT**                         **VOLUME**                    **CHARGEABLE**                **PACKAGES**\n                                                                         398.000 KG                     4.999 M3                  833.500 KG                12 PLT\n    FLIGHT / DATE                                                                                       **MAWB**                                    **HAWB**\n    / MB756 /                                                                                           **2394746354**                             **SBCA20083746**\n    GOODS COLLECTED FROM            SGSIN = Singapore , Singapore              ETD 07-Jan-20            GOODS DELIVERED TO        MYSHA = Alam , Malaysia     ETA   09-01-20 15:00\n\n    ORIGIN                          SGSIN = Singapore, Singapore               ETD    08-01-20 19:30    DESTINATION               MYKUL = Kuala Lumpur, Malaysia ETA     08-01-20 20:30\n\n    CHARGES\n    DESCRIPTION                                                                                                                         GST IN USD                CHARGES IN USD\n    **Freight charge - 833.5 KG @ USD 0.68/KG                                                                                            Zero   Rated                        566.78\n    Terminal Handling Charges   IOR FEE                                                                                                Zero   Rated                      1,200.00\n    Handling - 833.5 KG @ USD 0.50/KG                                                                                                  Zero   Rated                        416.75\n    Delivery Cartage - 833.5 KG @ USD 0.25/KG                                                                                          Zero   Rated                        208.38\n    Fuel Surcharge - 833.5 KG @ USD 0.25/KG                                                                                            Zero   Rated                        208.38\n    War Risk Surcharge - 833.5 KG @ USD 0.14/KG                                                                                        Zero   Rated                        116.69**\n\n\n\n\n    TOTAL CHARGES\n    Please contact us within 7 days should there be any discrepancies.                                                            SUBTOTAL                               2,716.98\n    Interest rate of 1.5% per month will be charged on overdue invoices.                                                              ADD GST                                0.00\n    NEW: Payment available
```

So my problem is I want to extract all sub headings under DESCRIPTION column along with corresponding price under CHARGES IN USD column and save them as a dictionary even when sub headings strings are not same across different text files.

Comment: It would help if you could paste an example of the raw text file you are reading from.

Comment: The above data is from the raw text string. The issue is each raw text string has almost all other lines same, except the part under Description where the sub headings change. So that is why I provided two Description part of the bigger text string

Comment: Have added the complete data with what dictionary output I am aiming for.

Answer (score 0):

What are same in the headings?
Maybe that all of them located in the begining of the row, and ends with a dash separated with spaces. So the right regex should look something like this: 
`^([^\-]*)\s\-.*Zero Rated\s*(.*)`

Comment: but how will it extract the heading names and the price at the very end for all? The problem is I want to extract the sub headings with its price. But sub headings are not standard strings. Their names are different for different text files. All sub headings are though part of a DESCRIPTION heading which is same for all

Comment: ([^\-]*) matches everything until a dash, and tkaes them into a group. So it'll match the sub headings. I don't see exatly how your input looks like, because you attached only images of it. Maybe pure text would help more.

Comment: If the input is the data I attached above with DESCRIPTION as the text string and sub headings under it.. how can we get the above dictionary format where keys are sub headings and values are price?

Comment: I have added the full data with what fields I am looking to extract as a dictionary

Answer (score 0):

Maybe splitting like this:

```
#output = re.sub(' +', ' ', output)
subheader = output.split("Zero Rated")[0].split("-")[0].strip()
value = output.split("Zero Rated")[2].strip()
dict.update( {subheader : value} )
```

Comment: whats the reason for replacing + with ' '? Where is the + sign?

Comment: It replaces multiple spaces with only one. But can be omitted, I added it only for readability, but I remove it then.

Comment: this is  not working. It is extracting string from top of the text.. If u look at the data I attached.. and use that as the output string.. then this thing is not fetching sub headers under DESCRIPTION. We need to find regex for sub headers under DESCRIPTION header and the corresponding prices

Comment: You could split the data into list by line, than iterate on them

Comment: Yes thats what I did.  I wrote an answer for the same. Need to extract the part between DESTINATION and TOTAL CHARGEs as per the string. 

Then use splitlines etc. 

Could you help ans this? 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61588010/extracting-specific-values-for-a-header-in-different-lines-using-regex/61588605#61588605

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you normalize first?
There you go:

```
import re
text = '''Freight charge - 833.5 KG @ USD 0.68/KG                                                                                            Zero   Rated                        566.78
Terminal Handling Charges   IOR FEE                                                                                                Zero   Rated                      1,200.00
Handling - 833.5 KG @ USD 0.50/KG                                                                                                  Zero   Rated                        416.75
Delivery Cartage - 833.5 KG @ USD 0.25/KG                                                                                          Zero   Rated                        208.38
Fuel Surcharge - 833.5 KG @ USD 0.25/KG                                                                                            Zero   Rated                        208.38
War Risk Surcharge - 833.5 KG @ USD 0.14/KG                                                                                        Zero   Rated                        116.69'''

list = [(re.split('\s{5,}', x)) for x in text.split('\n')]

rdd = []
for i in list:
    rdd.append((i[0].replace('  ', ' - ').split(' -')[0], i[2]))

print(rdd)
```

Answer (score 0):

So I figured that out.

The best way is to extract the part of the string which is between DESTINATION and TOTAL CHARGES.

This will extract the string between these.

Now we need to extract the sub headers under this. For this we first splitlines and then create each line as list of words.

```
# Extracting the cost break up
cost_breakdown = re.search(
    r'(?s)(DESCRIPTION\s*GST IN USD\s*.+?TOTAL CHARGES)', output).group()

cost_breakdown = [
    re.split(r'\s{2,}', line.strip()) for line in cost_breakdown.splitlines() if line !=''
]

# dictionary of cost line items
cost_line_items = {line_item[0]: float(line_item[2]) for line_item in cost_breakdown[1:-1]}
```